# Pygame в .exe | pyinstaller | проблема с командной строкой

Tags: python, cmd, pygame, pyinstaller, командная-строка

`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3930] (c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.`

```
C:\Users\Руслан>pip3 install pyinstaller
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (6.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=42.0.0 in c:\program files\python311\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4 in c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2024.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=22.0 in c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2022.5.30 in c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2023.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.1 in c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.2)

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

C:\Users\Руслан>pyinstaller
"pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\Руслан>python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\python311\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)
Collecting pip
  Obtaining dependency information for pip from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/aa/3f4c7bcee2057a76562a5b33ecbd199be08cdb4443a02e26bd2c3cf6fc39/pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Downloading pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 3.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.11.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-23.3.2

C:\Users\Руслан>pyinstaller
"pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\Руслан>PyInstaller
"PyInstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.


.
.
.
.
```

Главная проблема в этой штуке. и то же самое он печатает на любые другие команды

`"PyInstaller"` не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

брал пример с этого поста https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/143934/

файл `main.py` находится в `C:\projects\ShawarmaClicker`

Comment: А переустановить не пробовали?

Comment: При установке `pyinstaller.exe` появляется в подкаталоге `python311\Scripts`, в вашем случае какая-то странность установки питона, по логам видно, что питон в двух местах - `c:\program files\python311` и `c:\users\руслан\appdata\roaming\python\python311` вероятно,  это проблема.  Так что можно бы и питон переустановить. Я, например, при установке выбираю каталог `c:\python311`, чтобы путь был покороче и без пробелов.